# Pasting non-text data (image) from system clipboard

Tags: os-clipboard

I would like to write a plugin  which will be triggered at paste from system clipboard if it contains image data. Is it feasible to do this with scripting? My preference is to write in Python, using neovim is also possible. The image would be then saved to file and its name inserted into the edited text.

Comment: For now your question is too broad to be kept open: It involves how to trigger an action at pasting, detecting that the data in the clipboard is an image (which probably shouldn't be Vim's job), how to save the image to a file (which isn't Vim's job neither), how to get the name of the new file, etc... So I will close the question and you should instead ask for help for a precise problem you'll have when implementing your plugin.

Comment: @statox okay, you're right :)

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14114/paste-link-to-image-in-clipboard-when-editing-markdown

Comment: FWIW, I got halfway through turning my answer to that question [into a plugin](https://github.com/sedm0784/vimclipaste/tree/develop). It's functional, but I ran out of steam before implementing all the features I was planning so it's never been released. I'm still planning to pick it development again one day, so I hope you don't beat me to market!

Comment: @Rich the dupe is well spotted, thanks! I cooked something up using python (in vim) and xclip now. Please feel free to close the question.